# running external program in TCL

Tags: events, tcl

After developing an elaborate TCL code to do smoothing based on Gabriel Taubin's smoothing without shape shrinkage, the code runs extremely slow. This is likely due to the size of unstructured grid I am smoothing. I have to use TCL because the grid generator I am using is Pointwise and Pointwise's "macro language" is TCL based. I'm still a bit new to this, but is there a way to run an external code from TCL where TCL sends the data to the software, the software runs the smoothing operation, and output is sent back to TCL to update the internal data inside the Pointwise grid generation tool? I will be writing the smoothing tool in another language which is significantly faster.

Comment: Yes, of course.  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: Which language were you thinking of using, and were you going to integrate the other language as a separate program or as a DLL? (Using another language is not a bad decision, BTW.)

Comment: Fortran 2003. It's my primary computing language. Since the method I am using for unstructured mesh smoothing with shape preservation is Jacobi iterative, it is well suited for shared memory multi-threaded operations. I'll accelerate the code with _Open MP_ for even better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options to deal with code that "runs extremely show". I would start with determining how fast it must run. Are we talking milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours or days. Next it is necessary to determine which part is slow. The `time` command is useful here.

But assuming you have decided that more performance is necessary and you have some metrics for your current program so you will know if you are improving, here are some things to try:

1. Try to improve the existing code. If you are using the `expr` command, make sure your expressions are given to the command as a single argument enclosed in braces. Beginners sometimes forget this and the improvement can be substantial.
2. Use the `critcl` package to code parts of the program in "C". `Critcl` allows you to put "C" code directly into your Tcl program and have that code pulled out, compiled and loaded into your program.
3. Write a traditional "C" based Tcl extension. Tcl is very extensible and has a clean API for building extensions. There is sample code for extensions and source to many extensions is readily available.
4. Write a program to do the time consuming part of the job and execute it as a separate process and obtain the output back into your Tcl script. This is where the `exec` command comes in useful. Presumably you will have to write data out to some where the program can get it and read the output of the program back into your Tcl script. If you want to get fancy you can do two-way communications across a localhost TCP port. The set up in Tcl is quite simple. The "C" code in a program to do it is a bit more tedious, but many examples exist out on the Internet.

Which option to choose depends very much on how much improvement is required and the amount of code that must be improved. You haven't given us much idea what those things are in your case, so all I can offer is rather vague general solutions.

Comment: SWIG can be used to generate a Tcl interface to a C or C++ piece of code. The interface doesn't feel very natural (it still feels like C or C++) but it is a good way to get something working quickly.

Comment: I  followed the information provided in "Practical Programming in TCL and Tk" by Welch, Jones and Hobbs. Fortunately, item **1** in your list is what I used. I am actually at item **4**, and confused. But  I will try to code something with the `fileevent` capability and ask for help when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

For a loadable module, you can write a Tcl extension.  An example is here:

[File Last Modified Time with Milliseconds Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260051/file-last-modified-time-with-milliseconds-precision/51260646#51260646)

Alternatively, just write your program to take input from a file.  Have Tcl write the input data to the file, run the program, then collect the output from the external program.