# how to use Tcl-C API on C++ code

Tags: c++, api, tcl

I am currently learning how to use Tcl-C api , I am reading "practical programming in Tcl and Tk - Fourth Edition" but I find very difficult to understand how actually the API is working when I have an program in C++ that I want to do a wrapping functions using this API that will provide me a shared object that will be loaded by my script.

I will try to be more clear.
suppose I have the following C++ file:

```
/* example.h */
Class A {
private:
   std::vector<int> data;
public:
   A(){}
}
```

and the C wrapper file:

```
/* match.c */

    #include <tcl.h>
    #include "example.h"

    // should create an instance of an A object for future use.
    int Tcl_ACmd (clientData, interp, argc, argv)
    // should take an instance of an A object that was created and return it's data vector.
    int Tcl_AGetDataCmd(clientData, interp, argc, argv)

    int Match_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp)
    {  
      if (NULL == Tcl_InitStubs (interp, TCL_VERSION, 0)) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
      }

      Tcl_CreateCommand (interp, "A", Tcl_MaxCmd, (ClientData)NULL,(void (*)())NULL);
      Tcl_CreateCommand (interp, "get", Tcl_MaxCmd, (ClientData)client_data,(void (*)())NULL);  

      return Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "Match", "1.0");
    }
```

and finally the script:

```
 # script.tcl
    $> load match.o
    $> A   (This will create an A instance)
    $> A get   (this will return the data of A)
```

Now , I understood that when I invoke the AGetData command the ClientData is actually void* type that should be casted to A class.
But Still I don't really understand how to pass the parameters to the wrapping functions (should I change argv with Tcl_Obj?) and where to the objects are created and how can I trace them for invoking there methods later by the script.

Comment: Your `.c` file is nevertheless C++ code if it compiles with the header included as shown. Just beacuse you use a C-alike coding style does not make your code C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to call C++ code from C (always a problem due to C++'s name mangling), create the C++ code to call the C routines.  The somename_Init procedures
and the somenameCmd procedures need to be declared as 'extern "C"' in the C++ code 
so that Tcl can find them when loading the shared library.

I would start with a working example:

[File Last Modified Time with Milliseconds Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260051/file-last-modified-time-with-milliseconds-precision/51260646#51260646) has a full example in C.

Then make the modifications to make it compile and usable with C++.

Then make the changes to use the names you want and the changes to support your C++ class.

There's also a C++ example at: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/21007

It appears that it creates a new Tcl command for each object it creates.
This is one possible solution.

Another possibility is adding each new object to a namespace ensemble.

Or keeping the C++ object handles saved in a data structure within the new
Tcl command, and access them via some sort of index.

Another possibility would to be to actually create a Tcl object handle for
each object.  This is rather more complicated.

It all depends on your use case requirements.
Of course a singleton object is much simpler.

Comment: _Only_ the `somename_Init` function needs `extern "C"`. Command implementations just need to be functions or static methods; calling an instance method requires a bridging thunk (basically to get the instance out of the `ClientData` argument and do the calling).

Comment: Thank you...It was really helpful